# Docker bind9 dns server 'failed: permission'

Tags: docker, dns, permissions, bind9

Encountering a permissions issue. I do realize that I can follow the instructions on https://hub.docker.com/r/internetsystemsconsortium/bind9 and do `docker run` way with volumes attached but I would like to store these folders locally in a custom /home/ directory. Unfortunately, it gives me a permissions issue. Likely the `chmod` and `chown` needs to be ran.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:

    bind9:
        image: internetsystemsconsortium/bind9:9.16
        container_name: bind9
        ports:
        - 53:53/udp
        - 53:53/tcp
        - 127.0.0.1:953:953/tcp
        volumes:
        - ./etc:/etc/bind
        - ./cache:/var/cache/bind
        - ./lib:/var/lib/bind
        - ./log:/var/log
```

`docker logs bind9` reveals the following:

```
...
bind9    | 27-Dec-2021 14:34:19.139 loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'
bind9    | 27-Dec-2021 14:34:19.139 directory '/var/cache/bind' is not writable
bind9    | 27-Dec-2021 14:34:19.139 /etc/bind/named.conf:2: parsing failed: permission denied
bind9    | 27-Dec-2021 14:34:19.139 loading configuration: permission denied
bind9    | 27-Dec-2021 14:34:19.139 exiting (due to fatal error)
bind9 exited with code 1
```

Comment: Any solution for this? Same issue here.

Comment: See accepted answer.

Comment: I ended using volumes instead of bind mounts, but the accepted solution should do the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/rpyr4f/dockercompose_folder_permissions_bind9/

```
sudo chown 106:260 -R ./etc/
sudo chown 105:106 -R ./cache/
sudo chown 105:106 -R ./lib/
sudo chown 0:198 -R ./log/
```